# How creating a swaper for my token

Tags: token, swap

what is the best way of creating swap for my token in on the chain?
i know about creating swap using The Token Swap Program
but is there another way to be more robust for production level projects?

Answer (score 1):

This is a question of opinion, since you're asking for the best way to create a market for your token.  You can use any ecosystem project that allows you to create your own market, like Openbook Dex.

Keep in mind, however, that many projects actually use token-swap in production!